# How to resolve these Python errors in Django?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to make my way through the Django Project's tutorial.

I've made it as far as this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/#s-make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin but I'm seeing errors in some of the files, e.g. in the admin.py file:

```
from polls.models import Poll
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Poll)
```

I'm getting the error

```
Unresolved import: Poll
```

The models are defined as outlined in the tutorial:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

The tutorial states that when I restart the server after adding the admin file, I should see the Poll app referenced in the Admin page at 127.0.0.1:8000, but all I'm seeing is this:

[image: Model admin without registered models]

I'm also seeing

```
Unresolved import: Poll admin.py    /newProj/src/newProj/polls  line 0  PyDev Problem
Unresolved import: settings manage.py   /firstproject/firstproject  line 10 PyDev Problem
Unresolved import: settings manage.py   /newProj/src/newProj    line 10 PyDev
```

Are the errors the reason why I wouldn't be seeing the Site administration page updated with the Polls app?

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: http://klaith.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/pydev-unresolved-import-errors/

Comment: These are Pydev errors, not Python errors. Sounds like your IDE is getting in the way.

Answer (score 2):

`/newProj/src/newProj/polls` and `/firstproject/firstproject`... eeek, this looks to be honest like the source of a few problems. OK, a few concepts:

**Python packages**: All python applications can be comprised of packages. These are basically just directories containing a `__init__.py` file.

**How python finds packages**: Well, python can do one of two things when it looks for packages:

- If the current directory is a package, i.e. contains `__init__.py`, it can import from files in it.
- It can search on the python path (`PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or `sys.path` - same thing) and then down into sub packages.

**How django projects are laid out**: A default django project looks something like this:

```
project_folder/
    __init__.py
    settings.py      # config
    urls.py          # url config
    polls/
        __init__.py  # makes polls a package
        models.py    # models
        admin.py     # admin
        views.py     # app views
        forms.py     # per app forms
        urls.py      # per app urls
```

In this layout, there are two possibilities for your `admin.py` when you `runserver`:

- `from models import Poll` - this works because you're remaining within the scope of your package.
- `from polls.models import Poll` - works because `polls` is a package and so is the parent from where you're running `runserver`.

Although it's tempting, don't use `project_folder` as a package. It'll break the code as soon as you rename the dir (for example, during deployment).

So, with all that in mind:

- verify your `__init__.py` files exist in the right places and that you're using a directory structure kinda like the one above. Might be best to check outside the IDE too - IDEs can be... difficult.
- verify your path is searching where you think it is. The current directory should work just fine; if it isn't, you can see

  ```
  import sys
  print sys.path
  ```

  will allow you to view where you're looking. You can explicitly add the current directory, but you shouldn't need to.
- I don't like PyDev. Totally personal preference here, but I find it hard work, over and above the usual editor of choice + terminal + file browser. You might too, especially if you find the directory structure is radically different in your file browser as compared to what you think you have with the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Pydev, which add an additional layer of abstraction on the importing process.

Use a light text editor and a console for learning. You can switch to an IDE once the Python Path and the import logic are clear enough in your head so you can setup Pydev yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Are the errors the reason why I wouldn't be seeing the Site
>   administration page updated with the Polls app?

The answer to this question is in the same page, at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-form

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import newProj.poll.models
```

Comment: This is not valid python, and gives a `SyntaxError`.